# Requisição Post API Messenger com Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Preciso criar um método post que retorne estas informações para a API do Messenger com Spring Boot, se alguém puder dar uma luz agradeço.

O exemplo abaixo se encontra na documentação do Facebook Developers

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "messaging_type": "<MESSAGING_TYPE>",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "<PSID>"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa da classe [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), do Spring Boot. Ela permite a você realizar requisições HTTP de maneira bem fácil.

Para essa requisição, você precisa de 3 coisas: os headers, o json com os dados, a URL a ser chamada. Para criar o json, adicione a seguinte dependência ao seu projeto:

```
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
```

Eis o código comentado:

```
public void post(String token) {
  String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages? 
    access_token=".concat(token);

  //setando o header da requisição. Veja se a documentação pede algum
  //outro header além desse e adicione, se necessário
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

  //Montando o json esperado pelo Facebook
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  json.put("messaging_type", "Algum valor aqui");

  JSONObject id = new JSONObject();
  id.put("id", "valor do ID aqui");
  json.put("recipient", id);

  JSONObject text = new JSONObject();
  text.put("text", "hello, world!");
  json.put("message", text);

  //Criando o objeto que representa a requisição a ser enviada
  HttpEntity <String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity <String> (json.toString(), httpHeaders);
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

  //Chamada propriamente dita, com a resposta do Facebook mapeada para uma String
  String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, String.class);
}
```

Imprimindo o json que foi montado, tem-se este resultado:

```
{
  "messaging_type": "Algum valor aqui",
  "recipient": {
    "id": "valor do ID aqui"
  },
  "message": {
    "text": "hello, world!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente não funcionou, Retornando erro 400 indicando que a resposta está fora do padrão. sou novo na programação e estou tendo dificuldades. Recebi um trabalho onde preciso criar um bot do Messenger utilizando somente o Spring Boot. Estou seguindo este exemplo: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start/#build Minha aplicação está conectando via GET tranquilamente, recebo o BODY do messenger por um POST,  mas não estou conseguindo enviar um POST contendo uma o BODY da solicitação exigido junto com a resposta.

Comment: Editei a montagem do Json. Você pode testar novamente?

Comment: Só valeu! Me ajudou muito, deu certinho aqui. Obrigado

Comment: Marque a resposta como correta então. É importante para ajudar outros colegas que tiverem a mesma dúvida.